# OSError: Errno 30 Read-only file system: Any way to create a CSV and attach it to email from Python in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, html-email, smtplib

So I am trying to create a Lambda Function to Query from MySQL Database and write the query output to a CSV file, attach the created file as an attachment and send an email using Python.

I have a working code to achieve this, but unable to execute the same in *AWS Lambda*.

Here's the code I'm working on right now:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://username:password@MYSQL DB Creds")
con_mysql = engine.connect()

#dump_attachment_query_link
attach = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM some_table)",con_mysql)


#NAMING_FILES
#start,yest are dates
def filenames(start, yest):

if start == yest:
    return "Dump_{}.csv".format(yest)
  else:
    return "Dump_{}_to_{}.csv".format(start, yest)

attach.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
att = attach.to_csv(filenames(start, yest))


files = filenames(start, yest)

def send_mail(fromaddr, subject, message):
    access_token, expires_in = refresh_authorization(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN)
    auth_string = generate_oauth2_string(fromaddr, access_token, as_base64=True)

    msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
    msg['Subject'] = subject + ": %s" %yest
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = "receivers'mail"
    msg.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'
    msg_alternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg.attach(msg_alternative)
    part_text = MIMEText(lxml.html.fromstring(message).text_content().encode('utf-8'), 'plain', _charset='utf-8')
    part_html = MIMEText(message.encode('utf-8'), 'html', _charset='utf-8')
    msg_alternative.attach(part_text)
    msg_alternative.attach(part_html)

    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open(files, "rb").read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename = {}'.format(files))
    msg.attach(part)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
    server.starttls()
    server.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + auth_string)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr,msg['To'].split(",") + msg['Cc'].split(","), msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

When I use the code I get the following error - [ERROR] OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'Dump_{}*to*{}.csv'

I'm quite new to Lambda and Python. 
Any help regarding this is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Error says you cannot write to file system. According to code you try to create CSV files there.

1. You don't need to create real files to create an attachment. In memory streams are enough.
2. Your Lambda is allowed to write to /tmp directory.